# android: set background color for the entire screen dynamically, or how to set actionbar to overlay layout, but not overlap content

Tags: android, android-actionbar, background-image, android-theme, titlebar

My app uses the Theme.Wallpaper family, which means the current wallpaper is used as the app's background.
This may cause readability issues (depending on the user's favorite wallpaper) so I want to allow the user to choose an image as a background.

The way I am trying to implement it is:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // Get wallpaper preferences to check if user selected a wallpaper and
    // display it
    SharedPreferences wallpaperPref = getSharedPreferences(WallpaperActivity.WALLPAPER_PREFERENCES, MODE_PRIVATE);
    int selectedWallpaper = wallpaperPref.getInt(WallpaperActivity.SELECTED_WALLPAPER, 0);
    if (selectedWallpaper != 0) {
        findViewById(R.id.pager).setBackgroundResource(selectedWallpaper);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(selectedWallpaper));
    } else {
        findViewById(R.id.pager).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

The shared preference contains the resource id of the selected wallpaper.

My problem is the titlebar and actionbar do not respond to this. Is there a way to make them also receive the new background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make the background of the title bar and action bar transparent.
2. Set your [Window ActionBar Overlay](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowActionBarOverlay) to true.
3. Pad your main view by the height of the ActionBar so the ActionBar doesn't cover up any of the content.

Your ActionBar will now sit over the background view, instead of above it. It will be transparent, so as to allow the background to show through, and it will not be covered up by the ActionBar.

Comment: Why would they have an opaque background color? tried it anyway, didn't work.

Comment: Why? I don't know. Do they? I'm sure the reason that your ActionBar is not showing the same background is because it's using its own background.

Comment: Well, setting their background to transparent didn't help. Also, as I mentioned - my app is using phone's wallpaper as background. In my case, it's a photo of a wind turbine. The photo is spread across the entire screen, the top of it is spread under the actionbar and the titlebar. So it seems like they arn't using their own backgrouns, but they don't reside on the layout I set in my layout file.

Comment: OK, then try taking a look at this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowActionBarOverlay

If you set this to true, perhaps the background will show through?

Comment: added "<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">false</item>" to my AppBaseTheme, didn't help. Is it the right way to use it? or should I put it somewhere else?

Comment: I would suggest you set it to true. That way it is overlaying your app, which in theory means that the background could show through if you set the ActionBar's background to transparent. If you set it to false, it sits above your application, and I imagine the background can't show through in that case.

Comment: Thanks @Sky, this works. Only now my contents are also overlapped by the actionbar. Any solution to this?

Comment: Find the ActionBar height, and pad the top of your view by that height. Oh, and mark this as the solution ;)

Comment: Any idea how to set padding to SettingsActivity, @Sky? as it has no layout file?

Comment: You should probably open a new question for that. And of course, mark this as the answer.

Comment: Sky, if I can't use your answer there is no point in marking it as accepted. I'll try to make it work for some time, if I find a way I'll mark it as the accepted answer. I hope you understand.

Comment: You just asked how to view the background through the actionbar. You said this works. Hence, the question has been answered. Now you have a question about the padding. That is a different question. It's more useful to put new questions into separate posts, because then more people can help you answer it, and more people can be helped by your question. I'm not going to comment further on this question.

Comment: Feel free to post your own question and answer it. As long as I can't use your solution, it is not the accepted one. It is definitely not useful for me to accept a partial solution.

Comment: I found a solution, so you get the accept. Truly, you don't really deserve it. You had one good comment which I already up-voted. Other than that you didn't help much. I found most of the knowledge I needed on other places. But I made a promise so here you go - answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up doing, thanks to @Sky for the help:

1. On my app's style I added this item: `<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>` which makes the actionbar overlapp my layouts. This is the solution to the original problem, but of course it is not useable as long as the layout contents are overlapped, so here's how to overcome this:
2. On the dimen.xml file I added these two dimentions to be used as paddingTop values
   `dimen name="actionBarSize" 56.0dip dimen`,
   `dimen name="actionBarWithTabsSize" 112.0dip dimen`.
   (add the '<' and '/> in place)
   These are necessary to API 10 and below, for API-11 and above there is `?android:attr/actionBarSize` that can be set as the paddingTop value.
3. On each top-level layout - that is the top level element on every layout file that is being inflated by an activity, I added a paddingTop value like this: `android:paddingTop="@dimen/actionBarSize"` except on the layout in which I have tabbs implemented, there I used `android:paddingTop="@dimen/actionBarWithTabsSize"`.
4. On the preference.xml file in the xml folder, I added this line to the top-level PreferenceScreen element: `android:layout="@layout/activity_settings"`.
5. On the layout folder I created a new layout file named "activity_settings.xml". It contains a FrameLayout as the top-level element, with this property: `android:paddingTop="@dimen/actionBarSize"`, and within the FrameLayout there is one ListView element with id `android:id="@android:id/list"`.
6. On my PreferenceActivity sub-class, right after the call to `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);` I added `setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);`. This tells the preference activity to use the activity_settings.xml layout file as it's layout, and the ListView with id of "@android:id/list" as it's preference container. This way you get control of the top-level layout file in order to set it's padding.